# Magento Payment Method Signature

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-methods, payment-gateway

" **make sure to check the signature returned from Gateway to ensure that the payment response is coming from the payment page and not from a hacker who is trying to modify the payment response; and display a “security violation was detected!” message if the signatures mismatching occurred.** "

this message from external gateway but my question **how i can check this signature ?** i use `hash('sha256',..);` in php

Comment: Which payment gateway you are using. Are you trying to built a new custom payment method.

Comment: I'm used NetCommerce Payment gateway , yes i created a new custom payment method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the signature from **Gateway** per ***compare*** your **signature** with the **payment gateway** **signature** example :

```
$my_signature = '47783y74834332hd3873298392332';
$gateway_signature = '47783y74834332hd3873298392332'
if ($my_signature == $gateway_signature){ echo 'true'; }else{echo 'false';}
```